# Create dataframe of relationships per ID (From, To)

Tags: python

I have a sample dataframe:

```
data = {'IDs': ['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5'],
        'Terms': ["a", "b", "a", "d", "c", "f", "g", "a", "h", "i", "j"],
        'Values': [100, 100, 200, 200, 300, 300, 300, 400, 400, 500, 500]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['IDs', 'Terms', 'Values'])
```

Which creates this:

[image]

I want something that looks like the following table, where for each ID, the Terms underneath are mapped to the other terms within its ID with its respective value (I dont need both directions).

I really dont know where to start. I have tried looking at contigency tables, but nothing really looks like what I have. Any suggestions are really welcome.

[image]

Comment: Something like a `groupby` might help as a starting point.
`for _id, df_for_id in df.groupby("IDs"): print(_id, df_for_id)`

Might be easier to work with if you have these individual groupings

Comment: Thank you jean, I appreciate the help. I will take a look and see where I get to!

Comment: Sure thing. From each of these groupings you can build some data structure of your choice, then at the end merge everything into a dataframe with the columns `From, To, Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether this is the most efficient way or not. Using pands `groupby`

```py
l = []
for group_name, group in df.groupby(['IDs']):
    group.reset_index(inplace=True)
    for i in range(0, len(group)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(group)):
            l.append([group['Terms'][i], group['Terms'][j], group['Values'][i]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['From', 'To', 'Value'])
```

output

```
From    To  Value
0   a   b   100
1   a   d   200
2   c   f   300
3   c   g   300
4   f   g   300
5   a   h   400
6   i   j   500
```

Comment: Thank you Epsi95! Perfect, does exactly what I need it to :)

Comment: The From/To `f`, To/From `g`, Value `300` is missing from this solution. See above/below for one that [produces all the combos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65906161/1431750).

Comment: @aneroid thank you for pointing out that. Corrected!

Comment: @ScoutEU there was a mistake in the previous solution. Please check the corrected one now.

Comment: Oh I did not notice. Thank you for checking!

Answer (score 1):

Since ID's isn't present in your result, and Values are the same when IDs are the same - using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
res = df.drop('IDs', axis=1).groupby(['Values']).apply(
        lambda x: list(itertools.combinations(x['Terms'], r=2))
    ).explode()
pd.DataFrame(res.to_list(), index=res.index, columns=['From', 'To']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Values From To
0     100    a  b
1     200    a  d
2     300    c  f
3     300    c  g
4     300    f  g
5     400    a  h
6     500    i  j
```

Comment: Thank you very much aneroid!! :)